# Setlocale returns false (WAMP)

Tags: php, localization, gettext, setlocale

I have working localization in my project. Working means that my project gets translated to whatever language I have in the `locale/sk` folder, `sk` for slovak being my default system language.

Setting to any other language doesn't work. I have tried `$lang = 'cs'`, `'cz'`, `'en'`, `'en_UK'`, `'en_UK.utf8'` and others. Still, only the translation in the `'sk'` folder is taken and still the `setlocale()` function returns false. I have tried to change default language in browser - no effect.

This is my code:

```
putenv("LANG=$lang"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang); 
bindtextdomain("messages", realpath("../localem")); 
textdomain("messages");
...
_("Welcome!")
```

I have also tried these:

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=$lang"); 
putenv('LC_ALL=$lang');
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit:

```
$loc = array('nor');
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, $loc)==false) print ' false'; else print setlocale(LC_ALL, $loc);
```

`'nor'` prints `Norwegian (Bokmĺl)_Norway.1252`, `'rus'` russian, but `'svk'` prints false and so does `'cze'`.

On the list all of these are mentioned:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses another format for the locale setting, see [MSDN: List of Country/Region Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You can send a list of locales to setlocale by sending in an array, such as to get Norwegian month names and time formats:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('nb_NO.UTF-8', 'no_NO.UTF-8', 'nor'));
```

Windows might however return strings in another encoding than UTF-8, so you might want to handle this manually (converting from cpXXXX to UTF-8).

Comment: thanks for reaction. I edited my question, to report progress (still can't figure it out and now I am starting to get confused)

Comment: also, even thought I do not get false, none of translations in folders 'no', 'nor', or 'no_NO' is taken, but still the one in the 'sk' folder.

Comment: It's impossible to say what kind of logic is present to find the translation without you pasting that information as well. For all we know that might not even depend on the value of setlocale.

Comment: I use gettext. I added an example: _("Welcome!")